# MLE for two-parameter exponential distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, exponential-family

I have to find the parameters of a two-parameter exponential distribution using the MLE. But imposing first order conditions, I do not find enough conditions to found both the paramenters.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your second parameter do?  Shifted exponential?  Something else?  A good starting point is to define the pdf ...

Comment: Please expand abbreviations (in this case, "FOC") on first use. Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying the question as needed.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298874/mle-for-2-parameter-exponential-distribution

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the shifted exponential distribution with p.d.f $$\lambda e^{\lambda(t_i-\gamma)}$$ The maximum likelihood estimate for a sample $(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is given by $$\gamma = \min_i t_i$$ and $$\lambda = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n (t_i-\gamma)}$$.

You'd probably be better off with a prior on $\gamma$ though.